# How to get np.char.add() to put a space between the concatenated strings

Tags: python, numpy

I need a space between the strings that are concatenated by np.char.add()

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.array(['Indiana', 'Cincinnati', 'Purdue', 'Ball State'], dtype=np.str)
arr2 = np.array(['Hoosiers', 'Bearcats','Boilermakers', 'Cardinals'], dtype=np.str)
teams = np.char.add(arr1, arr2)
print(teams)
```

and I get this:

```
['IndianaHoosiers' 'CincinnatiBearcats' 'PurdueBoilermakers'
 'Ball StateCardinals']
```

I need this:

```
['Indiana Hoosiers' 'Cincinnati Bearcats' 'Purdue Boilermakers'
 'Ball State Cardinals']
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.array(['Indiana', 'Cincinnati', 'Purdue', 'Ball State'], dtype=np.str)
arr2 = np.array(['Hoosiers', 'Bearcats','Boilermakers', 'Cardinals'], dtype=np.str)
teams = np.char.add(np.char.add(arr1, " "), arr2)
print(teams)
```